This man offered me money for a sex video - Is it a scam?
We talked just today in an online dating app. His bio says “I’m a giver and I’m happy to help other people”.
He messaged me asking about my life. Then after a minute he offered me 2000 USD just for a sex video call, and he said he will send the money through Western Union. I said send it first. He claimed he’s willing to send the money first and is asking my name and what country and city I live in.
I asked if we can have a video call so I can believe that he’s real and not a scammer, but he refused; he wants to hide his face in any video call.
So tell me is this a scam or real?

It's a scam. Block him and move on.

This question is similar to: Am I being scammed by a sugar daddy?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Actually he called me jacking off lol then he asked me if I want to do it and I said no I can’t. Then he said “Fuck off then stupid bitch” I said if he’s real he should send it in my Paypal or cash app but he refused he said he only have Western Union, so tell me, is it still a scam?

It's still a scam.

If it is too good to be true then it is most likely not true. You could be set up for identity theft, blackmail, money laundering, any number of things. Unless you're ready and willing to see your sex video all over the internet, I suggest you follow @Vicky's advice.

If he became abusive the moment you said no, why would  you believe he is in any way legitimate?

Don’t understand the downvotes. It is a very reasonable question if you don’t know the answer. And both OP and anyone else with the same question can enormously fit from a correct answer.

Remember that once that person has recorded your video, it is very likely to end up on public sites or be otherwise distributed. And of course you won’t see a cent. Probably the opposite.

Most likely, it's going to be blackmail.  He's asking for personal details so he can identify you.  Then he records the video call.
At the end of the call, he would demand that you send all his money back, and more money on top.  If not, he will post the recording on the internet or send it to your relatives.

Or he sells the video. Or the payment bounces; see many past answers tagged "scam" for how that works. Hiding his face is an attempt to protect himself from prosecution, as is the insistancee on trying to send the money in a way that doesn't require he identify himself. Note that if you're underage (in your country or in his)  this may be illegal even if you agree to it. Frankly, if the first thing he does is offer you money for a sex video he isn't someone whom you want to give your address to. He's certainly not a "giver"; he's a buyer at best

Unlike most “Is it a scam questions”, where the details of the question provide the answer, this question isn’t so simple.
This is entirely different from the supposed duplicate, as this guy isn’t asking for details that he doesn’t need nor asking you to use your money to pay his bills.
Scams such as that are easy to spot, they are too good to be true, or too bad to be true (in the case of supposed over payments that can’t be clawed back).
In this case, it isn’t unreasonable to suppose that this is at least a semi-honest offer of a quid-pro-quo. He may or may not intend to use the resulting video more widely than you believe, but the basic 2k for a custom sex video call isn’t unbelievable.
Instead of asking if this guy is a scammer, the real question is what if he is just shady? 2k for a sex video, that may be a bit expensive for a jerk-off session, it’s probably about half of what it would cost to hire a professional.  Are you prepared for him to take your video and sell it? Even if it’s for personal use now, you’ve said things that indicates the guy has a temper, it could be 100% legitimate today, but what’s going to happen tomorrow after you piss him off by not doing another video or asking too much, or not answering his call quickly enough, or whatever…
You may end up wishing it was just a scam that cost you a few hundred dollars.
If you want to be in porn, look for a reputable company to deal with, not some fly by night jerk that’s unlikely to abide by any agreement you make.
And if you don’t want to be in porn, it doesn’t matter, cut all contact with him.
